# What is this programmer doing with his Lookup function?

Tags: excel-formula

I found on a forum a formula to find the last populated cell in a column:

```
LOOKUP(2,1/(G:G<>""),ROW(G:G)))
```

But what's going on with this bit?

```
1/(G:G<>"")
```

One divided by ??? (something that's not equal to ""?) I don't understand the logic, here.

Comment: G:G<>"" will return an array of TRUE/FALSE for each cell in column G - TRUE if it contains a value, FALSE if it doesn't.  `1/False = #DIV/0` and `1/TRUE = 1`.  The lookup value (`2`) is then searched for - and not found, so the largest value that is less than 2 is returned - this is the last 1 value.  That position in the array is then used to return the row number from the second array giving the last row number..... _I think_.

Comment: Use `Evaluate Formula` on this cut down version to get an idea of how it works:  `LOOKUP(2,1/(G1:G10<>""),ROW(G1:G10)))`

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks Darren. The next question is, then: why is the "1/(" bit used? If we get rid of it, the formula starts to only output "N/A", but it doesn't seem necessary because it's not giving any new info. 1/TRUE ... or 1/1 is still... 1. Nothing has changed. Why can't it search for the "TRUE" without needing the "1/"? The obvious answer is that it changes the "TRUE" string into a number but it'd be interesting to find out the mechanism behind this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to observe the calculation step by step by evaluating the formula with Formula Auditing I strongly recommend limiting the range. Say apply:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(G1:G10<>""),ROW(G1:G10))
```

And, for illustration purposes, populate no lower down the sheet than say G6 (but a void between, in the range G1:G5, may in that case help to understand what is happening).

For this answer I am only going to consider five cells: G1, G3 and G4 populated, G2 and G5 (onwards) not.

```
1/(G1:G5<>"")
```

Is indeed at the heart of this formula. `G1:G5<>""` does, as you have recognised, test whether *not equal to ""*. `""` is the convention for 'empty' for an Excel cell. If populated (ie "not empty") this returns TRUE and FALSE otherwise. Hence for the five cells as chosen for this example an array is returned, regarding G1:G5 in order, of:

`TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE`.

In arithmetic calculations Excel treats TRUE as `1` and FALSE as `0`. Hence using the above truth table as the denominator and `1` as the numerator gives an array (again in order) of:

`1/1;1/0;1/1;1/1;1/0`

which resolves to:

`1;#DIV/0!;1;1;#DIV/0!`.

In the LOOKUP function above `2` was chosen as the [lookup_value](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/LOOKUP-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb). (Any other number greater than 1 would serve equally well.) So we are looking for `2` in an array that is composed exclusively of either `1`s or errors. Therefore there is no chance of finding an exact match, so the default kicks in, which is the last value (in order, not counting errors). The last `1` in the array is the fourth element, and the fourth element in ROW(G1:G5) is …`4`.

G4 is the last populated cell in ColumnG (in my example).