# Counting Blank and Non-Blank cells

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to count all the blank and non-blank cells in a given range of data only until the cell with a data. But I also have a limited to refer on only, its from `O4:O18`.

[image: sample2] [image: sample3]

Given from the sample above, I only have to count blank cells from Row4 to the cell with data which is `asd`. Any help? Thanks!

The use of count is to count the blank cells within the non-blank cells. lets say that the last row with data is 15, so 15 will be the last row with data and from row 4 to row 15, will count the blank cells in the Range.

Comment: Won't they all be blank if you're counting from start cell to first cell with data?  Will it always start on row 4?

Comment: So you want to get number of blank cells and non-blank cells in the Range("O4:O18") ?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Yes it will always start in row 4, and will start to count the blank cells until the cell with a data. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want. Can you give 2 examples and tell us what the count is supposed to be ?

Comment: @Rémi Updated my question. Thanks

Comment: Then I do not understand what is the problem in my answer. I just do a small update for the MsgBox so you can test with your examples, it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can easely achieve desired result using `worksheetfunction`, try this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim iBlank&, iNonBlank&, rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("O4:O" & [O4:O18].Find("*", , , , , xlPrevious).Row)

    With WorksheetFunction
        iNonBlank = .CountA(rng)
        iBlank = .CountBlank(rng)
    End With

    MsgBox "Blank: " & iBlank & vbNewLine & "NonBlank: " & iNonBlank
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes this counts blank and non-blank cells. But what I want is to count only the cells that is blank within non-blank cells in the given range. Thanks.

Comment: Sweet and simple :) Thanks for this!

Comment: Just noticed something, why do you have a `&` in your variables?

Comment: @ramj it's just a shorthand way of declaring, `&` means `as Long`, `%` means `as Integer`, `$` means `as String`, `@` means `as Currency`, `!` means `as Single`, `#` means `as Double`, if nothing specified then variable will be `as Variant`

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure about what is your goal. I understand that you have a maximum range from "O4" to "O18" (it can be smaller) and you want to go from "O4" to the last non blank cell in that range, count the number of blank and non-blank cells. If it is indeed what you want to do, try the code below (explanations are in it):

```
Sub CountingBlankAndNonBlank()

    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long, TotalRange As Long
    Dim CountBlank As Long, CountNonBlank As Long

    'Find the last row with data in the Range("O4:O18")
    LastRow = 19 - Range(Cells(18, 15), Cells(Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp)).Count

    'Set a range from "O4" to last cell with data
    Set MyRange = Range(Cells(4, 15), Cells(LastRow, 15))

    'How many cells in my Range
    TotalRange = LastRow - 3

    'How many blank cells in my Range
    CountBlank = MyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count

    'How many non-blank cells in may range (Total - Blank)
    CountNonBlank = TotalRange - CountBlank

    MsgBox "There are:" & vbNewLine _
        & "  - " & CountBlank & " blank cells" & vbNewLine _
        & "  - " & CountNonBlank & " non-blank cells" & vbNewLine _
        & "  - " & LastRow & " would be the lastrow"

End Sub
```

Comment: It does the count the blank cells with in non-blank cells. But even if I add another non-blank cells in the column, it returns the same counts. Thanks

Comment: Its last row is always 13, why is it?

Comment: Did you copy my exact code? It works perfectly for me

Comment: Yep, I've copied all of it. 13 is always the lastrow returned .

Answer (score 0):

Count blank cells (returns 3 in your 2nd example and #N/A if all cells blank):

```
=COUNTBLANK($O$4:INDEX($O$4:$O$18,LOOKUP(2,1/($O$4:$O$18<>""),ROW($O$4:$O$18))-3))
```

Count non-blank cells (returns 6 in your 2nd example and 1 if all cells blank):

```
=COUNTA($O$4:INDEX($O$4:$O$18,LOOKUP(2,1/($O$4:$O$18<>""),ROW($O$4:$O$18))-3))
```

Using the Lookup formula from here: [What is this programmer doing with his Lookup function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38871745/what-is-this-programmer-doing-with-his-lookup-function#comment65105723_38871745)